# What is the correct fetch body in React with FileReader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, fetch, filereader

I have a React app which gets data from an upload. I want to send the data (mostly CSV's) row by row to my API. The problem is that I cannot get the correct value.

```
const uploadLocalFile = (file)  => (dispatch)  => {
 const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = evt => {
        fetch("some/api/here",
            {
                credentials: "same-origin",
                method: "POST",
                body: //file, evt.target.result ?? <--- 
            })
        }
    reader.readAsText(file)
    alert("done.")
}
```

`file` is the whole file, `evt.target.result` is not allowed in react? Is `evt.currentTarget` forbidden by fetch?

Comment: What does this have to do with React?

Comment: `fetch` returns a Promise right? I don't see you do anything with the return value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not allowed in react"? Passing this function as the handler for your file input should work:

```
handleSelectFile = (event) => {
  const file = event.currentTarget.files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const content = event.target.result
    // do whatever you want do do with `content`
  }
  reader.readAsText(file)
}
```